# Is the structure of the sentence OK?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Could you give me your advice about the structure of the sentence:

> That gives a single channel nearly twice the bandwidth of the older PCI and an eight-lane slot a data rate comparable to the fastest version of AGP.

is like:

That `gives` `a single channel` + `nearly twice the bandwidth (of the older PCI)`
and
(that) (gives) `an eight lane slot` + `a data rate (comparable to the fastest version of AGP)`.

Is this OK?

Comment: There needs to be some kind of punctuation or verbiage between *slot* and *a*. Or it should be rephrased. But it's ambiguous if the last part of the sentence is referring to only the last item or to everything, so it's impossible for me to understand the intended meaning. Also, among other things, I suspect there should be a *with* in front of *twice*, and some kind of noun after *PCI* and possibly *AGP*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is Okay.
"That gives a single channel nearly twice the bandwidth of the older PCI and an eight-lane slot a data rate comparable to the fastest version of AGP."
The meaning is a bit weird though. Try changing *comparable* to *compared*

Comment: Comparable here is used in the sense of being *on par* or *equivalent*